# XcodeのswiftでiPhoneアプリを作成していますが、Androidの暗黙的インテントの実装はどのようにするのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, xcode

流れとしましては
ゲームクリア時に選択ボタンを２つ配置し（知らせる、終わる）
終わるボタンでメインメニューへ戻る
知らせるボタンの場合、
アプリケーション選択画面を表示し、
『クリップボードにコピー、ドライブ、メール、・・・』
などの選択を促し確定しその後、メインメニューへ戻るという
内容を実現したと思います。

Androidの暗黙的インテントの実装は簡単に行うことは
できますか？
簡単にできるようであれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

iOSにはインテントに匹敵する汎用のアプリケーション間連携機能が存在しないので、「暗黙的インテント」を前面に出されると、全く同じことをするのは無理、という場合も少なくありません。

ただ、

> 知らせるボタンの場合、 アプリケーション選択画面を表示し、 『クリップボードにコピー、ドライブ、メール、・・・』
>   などの選択を促し確定しその後、メインメニューへ戻るという

と言うことであればiOS用のアプリによくあるshareボタンに近い動作ですので、[アクティビティ](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW122)でほぼ所望の動作は実現できそうに思います。

最初に書いたように、アプリ間連携に関しては、iOSとAndroidで考え方の大きく異なる部分ですので、機能デザイン・UIデザインとも修正を迫られる可能性も大きいですが、まずはiOSのアクティビティ機能でご自分のアプリの要件を満たせるかどうか精査されてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: Le Pere d'OO さん
ありがとうございます。 参考にさせていただきます。 アプリをAndoroidとiPhoneで同じアプリをそれぞれ公開しようとすると
内容によっては全く同じにできない場合があるということですね
最近ハイブリッドの開発環境が話題でAndoridoで作ったものを
iPhoneでもすぐに公開できるなどとありますが、
カスタマイズなどは必要になる場合が多いのでしょうか（内容にもよると思いますが）？

Comment: @マツモト さん、ご指摘のように一概には言えません。そのハイブリッド開発環境の特性をよく理解して作成された場合、ターゲットごとにビルドし直すだけで済むことも多いです。「各ターゲットの最大公約数的機能しか利用できない」という注記を見たことがあると思いますが、導入される前にどこまで対応可能かよく見極めて、自分のアプリに必要な機能がその開発環境の中から使用できるかどうか十分検討の時間を持たれた方がいいでしょう。ハイブリッド開発環境の多くはHTML/CSSを表示層に使っていて、立ち上げは簡単なのですが、その環境がサポートしていない機能にアクセスしようと思うと突然まともなドキュメントもない状態でネイティブのコードをそれぞれのターゲットに合わせて書かないといけない…なんて形でハードルの上がり方が半端なかったりします。十分ネット上の情報を活用して、明快な答えが見つからない部分については、また別の質問スレを立てられると良いかと思います。